# How route to aspx in razor view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I use razor view engine. 
I need get route url aspx view.

Example:

`<tag src="/ReportViewer.aspx" />` - The current implementation. file in the root of the site.

`<tag src="@Url.Action("ReportViewer", "Reports") />` - I need this construction. File path Views/Repors/ReportViewer.aspx

someone knows the solution ?

Comment: If you are loading an aspx page, it's *not* a controller action, so using Url.Action() would not be correct to do. There is no controller or action...

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute("ReportViewer", "Views/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx");

@Url.RouteUrl("ReportViewer") --> /Views/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx
```

Comment: The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @simplydenis I thought all you need is to construct the url